# How to use sentinel to know you have gone offline?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, sentinel, redis-sentinel, redis-py

I have a redis sentinel cluster configured with 5 nodes with the following IPs:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

I wish to find a simple way to determine if any server has gone **offline from its own point of view.**

On server **192.168.1.1** I tail the sentinel log file via:
**tail -f /var/log/redis/sentinel-6379.log**

I **pull the network cable** from the **192.168.1.1** server and I see the following messages in the log file on server **192.168.1.1**:

```
1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:56:31.189 # +sdown master mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379

1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.273 # +sdown slave 192.168.1.3:6379 192.168.1.3 6379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379
1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.273 # +sdown slave 192.168.1.4:6379 192.168.1.4 6379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379
1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.273 # +sdown slave 192.168.1.5:6379 192.168.1.5 6379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379

1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.214 # +sdown sentinel 88c16ee0855100cf25919c9113e97e83290965b0 192.168.1.2 26379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379
1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.273 # +sdown sentinel 97d7e4885a56a90144bd312f395e1d96788f1ebe 192.168.1.3 26379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379
1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.273 # +sdown sentinel f61240ca198c318e156a7d87f382728316b22a8e 192.168.1.4 26379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379
1567:X 21 Apr 2021 15:57:09.273 # +sdown sentinel f8c43aa0ffe4141ee5b09c1c78d253ae04e0d8bb 192.168.1.5 26379 @ mymaster 192.168.1.2 6379
```

I am also using **redis-py** https://pypi.org/project/redis/ in my python project to subscribe to the above **+sdown** messages like so:

```
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=26379, username='myusername', password='mypassword')
    p = r.pubsub()
    p.psubscribe('+sdown')
    p.psubscribe('-sdown')
    p.psubscribe('+switch-master')
    p.subscribe('+sentinel')

    while True:
        message = p.get_message()
        if message:
            print(message)
```

My question is how can I use these messages to determine that my server has gone **OFFLINE** as in when a network cable is pulled out?

Do I simply determine that all my **+sdowns** are received at the exact same time for example?
Is there another better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as you only want to talk to the sentinel, not a local master or replica.

I guess you can do as you suggest.
However, I reckon it would be much easier to simply execute a `SENTINEL MASTERS` command, every time you get an `+sdown` event, and inspect its result instead.